# Change Woocommerce variable product price, based on category and user role not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Title says it all.

Bellow code works as it should, for simple products. But I cannot figure out, why it has no influence on Variable products. I have been searching through the net for filter-hooks, and experimenting with a mix of different of bellow script. No luck so far.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price_for_category_role', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price_for_category_role', 10, 2 );
function custom_price_for_category_role( $price, $product ) {
    //Get all product categories for the current product
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $categories[] = $term->slug;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $categories ) && in_array( 'b2b', $categories, true ) && current_user_can('b2b') ) {
        $price = (($price * 1.25) / 3);
    }

    return $price;

}
```

Bonus question: What could be the reason that woocommerce_product_get_regular_price, has no effect.(also for simple products) I would like to have the code only apply to regular price, and ignore sales price.

Comment: What is the value of `current_user_can('b2b')` if you dump it?

Comment: its just a bool(). so:
bool(true)
if you are logged in as b2b user.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. Didn't look any further into it. The current task didn't really need the feature, it just bothered me that it wasn't working. I am on a new project where I will hit the issue again. Will post back, if I solve it.